# Websockets: how to handle sending different data to many clients

Tags: websocket

I'm having a play around with websockets and I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around some stuff. Specifically, being able to send a whole bunch of subscribers different data without using a stupid amount of resources.

For example, if you had some sort of twitter like service, how would you send all followers of a person a newly posted tweet that they have made (and do the same for the other hundreds of people doing the same). It just seems that handling that many separate people is a bit absurd.

Can someone talk me through how you would go about treating each client individually? Please tell me if I have the whole idea of websockets wrong.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. for reference, I'm probably going to play around using either node or clojure (with aleph)

Comment: Hundreds of people is trivial to computers. It's not until you get into tens of thousands that you have to be clever.

Comment: Yeah that's sort of what I meant. It just seems like there's a better way than for each new client to subscribe to each of the people they are following when connecting or some such thing

Comment: The approaches vary drastically based on the number of users you need to handle. Once you get beyond a few hundred thousand, you start to want front end servers, middle servers, and back end servers. The front end servers handle connections to clients. The back end servers handle storage. The middle servers handle logical requests and ensure changes go to all interested listeners. The idea is that each middle server only has to deal with a small number of other middle servers, not hundreds of thousands of users.

Answer (score 0):

**Use an established messaging protocol and broker on top of websockets.**

It seems you are looking at websockets at the application layer when it is more of a network protocol. A variety of messaging APIs exists (such as JMS) with open source message brokers that are designed to do the complex and scalable message routing.